# How to bind WPF TextBox to a propperty that is the member of application main window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a private field

```
private static Double myValue;
```

in the application MainWindow class. And there (in the MainWindow class) I defined a property

```
public static Double MytValue
{
    get { return myValue; }
}
```

In the structure of the MainWindow class I have a TextBox. I'm in need of binding it to the MytValue property. In XAML I write:

```
<TextBox Name="tbxMyValue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" TextAlignment="Center"
         Text="{Binding Path=MyValue}" Width="Auto" Margin="10,0,10,15" IsEnabled="True" />
```

But it has no effect. I see nothing in the TextBox while myValue variable has a value. Why? Please help me.

Comment: Is it "MyValue" or "MytValue"?

Comment: I bag your pardon - it's MyValue ofcourse.

Answer (score 5):

I like to set the DataContext in the Window section

```
<Window x:Class="Gabe3a.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Gabe3a"
        xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
        xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource self}}"
        Title="Gabriel Main Ver 3a01" Icon="faviconw.ico" Height="600" Width="800">
```

Comment: nice, i never seen this before.

Comment: @Ewerton but not nice enough for a +1 ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `DataContext` behind the Window for that binding to work

There are two layers to an application with WPF: the UI layer and the data layer.

The Data layer for an application starts out as `null`, and you can set it using the `DataContext` property.

Whenever you do a basic binding in WPF, you are binding to the `DataContext`. So `Text="{Binding Path=MyValue}"` is actually saying "Get the `MyValue` property from the current `DataContext`".

You could simply set the `DataContext` in your code behind:

```
MyWindow.DataContext = this;
```

Or you can use a `RelativeSource` binding to tell WPF to get the `MyValue` property from somewhere else, such as telling it to get it from the closest Window it finds when navigating up the `VisualTree`:

```
Text="{Binding Path=MyValue, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

I actually have an article on my blog about the `DataContext` that I'd recommend reading if you're new to WPF and the `DataContext`: [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)

Comment: Congratulations, nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

It's not how it works. Binding to static properties; {Binding Source={x:Static local:Application.MyValue}}

Note that your field needs to be property & public. If you want to go with your solution, you need to set DataContext as {RelativeSource Self}.

Answer (score 0):

In file MainWindow.xaml.cs in constructor add this line:

```
DataContext = this;
```

after `InitializeComponent();`

Comment: So if MyValue is programmatically dynamically changed the value in text box will be accordingly changed each time?